# Laravel 5.4: redirect user to his account when user is login and try to go to login page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I have tree Auth guard (Customer, supplier, admin) and here is the `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` looks like

```
public function handle( $request, Closure $next, $guard = null ) {
        switch ( $guard ) {
            case 'supplier':
                {
                    if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) {
                        return redirect()->route( 'supplier-dashboard' );
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case 'admin':
                {
                    if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) {
                        return redirect()->route( 'admin-dashboard' );
                    }
                    break;
                }

            default :
                {
                    if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) {
                        return redirect( '/my-account' );
                    }
                }
        }

        return $next( $request );
    }
```

when I am logged in as supplier or admin and try to go to login page it takes me to the right `route`

but comes to the customer it takes me to the login page which is wrong here as I defined the  default case to redirect to `/my-account`

```
default :
                {
                    if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) {
                        return redirect( '/my-account' );
                    }
                }
```

What I am missing here?

> Solution

As @BilalAhmed suggest I debugged the return of `( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() )` and the result was `false` then I try `( Auth::guard( 'web' )->check() )` and this worked fine for me.

Comment: add this line into default case `dd(Auth::guard( $guard )->check() );` for debugging and check or share the output

Comment: @BilalAhmed I got `false`

Comment: @BilalAhmed Thanks a lot I got it I just replaced the `if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() )` with `if ( Auth::guard( 'web' )->check() )` and it worked fine.

Comment: i have add answer with complete details about guard.. i hope you will understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel (authenticate middleware) have two types of auth guard, `web` & `api`. for custom you must define in authenticate model like `protected $guard = 'customer';`

By default laravel used `web` like `Auth::guard('web')->user()`. it's similar to `Auth::user()`. also you can check default guard in `config/auth.php` file

when execute this line `if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() )` that's mean `Auth::guard( 'customer' )->check()` but there is no customer guard define in auth.php file

if you want to create custom guard then read [this articles](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-guard-in-laravel--cms-29667)

Comment: Thanks will read this article, about `config/auth.php` yes of course I have in my `guards` array something like this `'web' => [
   'driver'   => 'session',
   'provider' => 'users',
  ],`
and the `providers` array I have this `'users'     => [
   'driver' => 'eloquent',
   'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
  ],`
will check and read the article again, thanks dear